# Implementing drag and drop on relatively positioned elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I apologize for posting so many questions- I'm still learning! So, I can drag and drop the first element in the html no problem; however, when I try to drag and drop the second one, it appears *quite a bit* below the mouse. It still drags wherever I move the mouse, but far below. What's wrong?

Here is the javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", drag, false);

function drag(event) {
    if(event.target.className == "square") {
        element = event.target;
        posX = event.clientX -parseInt(element.offsetLeft);
        posY = event.clientY -parseInt(element.offsetTop);
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    }
}

function move(event) {

    if (typeof(element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}    

function drop() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<body>

<p class="square">Thing One</p>
<p class="square">Thing Two</p>

</body>
```

Here is the css:

```
/* CSS Document */

.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Thank you all for your time! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues to consider here:

1. How can I get the position of an element on the page?
2. What happens when I assign new values to the `left` and `top` style properties?

The answer to the **first question** relies on an understanding of `element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop`. These properties give the offset relative to `element.offsetParent` which is [defined as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent) "the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned containing element".

In your document this is the `<body>` element, so it works as you expected. If you were to place your squares inside other elements you'd find that your code would stop working. What you'd need is a function to walk up the tree of containing elements and sum each of the offsets, [like this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var pos= findPos(element);
posX = event.clientX - pos.x;
posY = event.clientY - pos.y;
```

Answering the **second question** requires an understanding of relatively positioned elements. Elements that are positioned relatively appear in a position *relative* to where they would normally appear on the page. When you assign values to `top` and `left` you're not giving absolute values. You're giving positions that are treated as relative to the element's original position in the layout. This is a feature of relative positioning, not a bug. You probably want to use `position: absolute;` instead.

Comment: So, it started working as soon as I turned the positioning to  `position:absolute;`; however, you're also saying that if they were nested in something else, they would still need the function because nesting them changes their positions depending on the parent element?

Comment: Right, so fixing the second issue will fix your immediate problem, but fixing them both will make the code a lot more future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using relative positioning somewhere, then the element's offset may not be relative to the top-left of the document.

you need to find the absolute offset of the element.

Comment: How do you suggest I find the absolute positioning of the element? I've only been javascript-ing for a few days now, and Google isn't helping me much.

Comment: Well, I don't want to use jQuery for that exact reason! I would rather have a nice feel for a language before jumping into a library (for shortcuts ect.). Especially if I switch to different libraries for different reasons. Can you explain the function they (codingforums) provide though? How is it different from what I did in the drag event?