# drag and drop div element work well on element one, but element 2 not well

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I've created a simple code to drag and drop two div elements but work well on `div 1` but `div 2` not work well.
The mouse cursor not Standing on `div 2` correctly.

Please check the online demo link in the bottom of the question.

**HTML**

```
<div class="draggable"></div>
<div class="draggable"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.draggable {
  background-color:yellowgreen; 
  width:150px; 
  height:100px; 
  border:1px solid #ffff66; 
  position:relative; 
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var element = null;
var elemPosL = 0;
var elemPosT = 0;
var isMouseDown = false;

document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    element = e.target;
    if (element.className === "draggable") {
        elemPosL = e.clientX - element.offsetLeft;
        elemPosT = e.clientY - element.offsetTop;
        isMouseDown = true;
    }
};

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        element.style.left = e.clientX - elemPosL + "px";
        element.style.top = e.clientY - elemPosT + "px";
    }
};


document.onmouseup = function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
    element = null;
};
```

[You can see online](http://jsfiddle.net/TJPF5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: absolute;` fixes it.

If you want relative, check [Implementing drag and drop on relatively positioned elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111492/implementing-drag-and-drop-on-relatively-positioned-elements-in-javascript?rq=1)