# Drag and drop position relative

Tags: javascript

Why when the ball is placed relative positioning when you press the mouse it bounces? Absolute positioning is when this doesn't happen.

```js
var ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

ball.onmousedown = function(event) {
  var shiftX = event.pageX - getCoords(this).left,
      shiftY = event.pageY - getCoords(this).top;

  this.style.position = 'relative';
  this.zIndex = 10000;

  function move(event) {
    this.style.left = event.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    this.style.top = event.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }

  move.call(this, event);

  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    move.call(ball, event);
  };

  this.onmouseup = function(event) {
    document.onmousemove = this.onmouseup = null;
  };
  
  return false;
};

ball.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

function getCoords(elem) {
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + window.pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + window.pageXOffset
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img class="ball" src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" alt="" />
```

I guess it's because of the padding of the body element. Please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing drag and drop on relatively positioned elements in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111492/implementing-drag-and-drop-on-relatively-positioned-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

it seems i found answer
[Implementing drag and drop on relatively positioned elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111492/implementing-drag-and-drop-on-relatively-positioned-elements-in-javascript)

and as it says, with **relative** position, your element contain offset of all objects in his parent-tag 
and parent's *margin* and *padding* too 
so when you try to get elemtn's position, you should count it's real offset in parent, see in my code example work with *count* index

```html
<html>

<body>


<div id=obj1 style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#000; position:relative; " ></div>
<div id=obj2 style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#000; position:relative; " ></div>
<div id=obj3 style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#000; position:relative; " ></div>

<script>

var dragObj, count=0;

function set_drag_drop(obj)
{
 if(count>0){
  // count margins and divs offset
  // body{ margin:10px; }
  // height:100px;
  obj.adx = 10; 
  obj.ady = 10 + (count*100)
 }else{
  obj.adx = 0;
  obj.ady = 0;
 }
 count++;
 
 obj.onmousedown = function(e)
 {
  var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
  obj.dx = rect.left - e.clientX;
  obj.dy = rect.top - e.clientY;
  obj.isDown = true;
  dragObj = this;
 }

 obj.onmouseup = function(e)
 {
  obj.isDown = false;
 }

 document.onmousemove = function(e)
 {
  if(dragObj && dragObj.isDown)
  {
   dragObj.style.left = e.pageX -dragObj.adx+ dragObj.dx +"px";
   dragObj.style.top = e.pageY -dragObj.ady+ dragObj.dy + "px";
  }
 }
}

set_drag_drop(document.getElementById("obj1"));
set_drag_drop(document.getElementById("obj2"));
set_drag_drop(document.getElementById("obj3"));

</script>
</html>
```